# Scale object and keep relative camera angle

Tags: camera, scale

[image]

I'm making a re-creation of a real-world picture of mine, and I want it to have accurate scale so that the falloff of my light looks correct. Problem is, my base mesh is far too big:

[image]

I want to scale down my base mesh, but I also need to keep the exact camera angle I've established. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to scale the camera with the object?

Comment: I dont really know whats the problem here. If you scale your whole scene you will end up with everything except the measures/dimensions exactly the same. It wont skrew anything. Also if you are using cycles for rendering it wont change anything for the render I guess (maybe the brigthness but I dont know...)

Answer (score 4):

Ah, silly me. I had the pivot point set to 'individual origins,' but setting it to 'median point' solves my scaling issue.